# Understanding Core Data Swift

Tags: ios, core-data

I am a super beginner in iOS development and I have a question regarding Core Data. I know this seems like such a stupid question but I have a really difficult time understanding what it is due to all the jargon that's involved in describing what it is. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data states:

`It allows data organised by the relational entity–attribute model to be serialised into XML, binary, or SQLite stores. The data can be manipulated using higher level objects representing entities and their relationships. Core Data manages the serialised version, providing object lifecycle and object graph management, including persistence. Core Data interfaces directly with SQLite, insulating the developer from the underlying SQL.`

Another link: http://shrikar.com/core-data-swift-tutorial/ states:

`Core Data framework provides a simple way of maintaining the life cycle of the objects and object graph management including persistence.`

And I searched on google, "What is core data swift" and most of the links are similar in their language and jargon. Therefore, it is really difficult more to understand what it does. Could you please explain what core data actually is in laymen terms?

*P.S. I think I understand basically what core data does. It just saves data so that I can use it later? But is this understanding sufficient for me to proceed in using core data? Or do I need a deeper understanding?*

Answer (score 1):

`CoreData` is a way for you to save data to use later. However, it can be much more powerful. It's an *Object-Graph* in the sense you can create `relationships` or *chain* multiple objects together to form so kind of relation.

In very simple applications, Core Data can be used as a `Dictionary` that doesn't lose the data upon closing your application. However, it can be so much more.

One application of `CoreData` that extends beyond a simple way to store data could be to save multiple "Person" objects and create the Follower/Following model used by many social applications. Perhaps you want to query your saved data model: "Find me all the users that have followed this person". Relationships that are established in Core Data will allow you to make this kind of query within the saved database.